# how do i increase the size of this SVG?

Tags: html, xml, svg

http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a5/Map_of_USA_with_state_names.svg

is it possible to increase the size of this map?

Comment: Can you describe the context for this question? Most SVG user agents (e.g. Firefox, Chromium, Apache Batik Squiggle) are able to zoom in on SVG images (try Ctrl++). However, if you're trying to rasterize the image (create a JPG, PNG, etc.), and increase the size of the rasterized output, you should look into an SVG rasterizer such as the Batik SVG Rasterizer: http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/tools/rasterizer.html

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes. As you know, SVG files are vector images, so you can simply zoom in when you view it.

But if you want to change the default size, then you can replace

```
<svg 
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   version="1.0"

   width="958.69"
   height="592.78998"

   id="svg2275"
   sodipodi:version="0.32"
   inkscape:version="0.46"
   sodipodi:docname="Map of USA with state names.svg"
   sodipodi:docbase="C:\temp\webdesign"
   inkscape:output_extension="org.inkscape.output.svg.inkscape">
```

with

```
<svg 
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   version="1.0"

   width="1917.38"
   height="1185.57996"
   viewBox="0 0 958.69 592.78998"

   id="svg2275"
   sodipodi:version="0.32"
   inkscape:version="0.46"
   sodipodi:docname="Map of USA with state names.svg"
   sodipodi:docbase="C:\temp\webdesign"
   inkscape:output_extension="org.inkscape.output.svg.inkscape">
```

That is, you define the `viewBox` (to `0, 0, <oldWidth>, <oldHeight>`), and then you can set the `width` and `height` as you wish. The above example thus doubles the width and height.

Comment: As a sidenote, I would remove all unnecessary metadata (such as paths on my own system) from a SVG created by Inkscape before publishing it.